# setprop persist.sys.timezone "America/Caracas" not reflecting the system time

Tags: android, time

i am facing a weird problem. I am using `setprop persist.sys.timezone "America/Caracas"` to modify my time zone from Asia/Calcutta. but this is not modifying the `system.currentTimeMillis()` values. but i can see that the time is updated in the `date` command. i tried to modify the timezone in the Date&Time settings page also,but getting the same results. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

```html
                    Time dtNow = new Time(); 
                    dtNow.setToNow(); 
                    int hours = dtNow.hour;
                    str = dtNow.format("%H:%M");
```

if i use this way, the time zone set by the Date&Time settings page will get reflected without any reboot. system.currentTimeMillis() will return UTC time.